# How to add files to uploader that is already running?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I am using s3.FineUploader and I am having troubles in reusing the uploader instance.
I want to be able to pick a file, hit Upload button, and then in the middle of first upload, pick a second file and hit Upload again. Is that supported somehow?

Could you tell me which option or method shall I use to accomplish what I need?

Thanks!

This is my currently failing code:

```
$(function() {
  uploaderParams = {
    multiple: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    element: $dropZone[0],
    request: {
      endpoint: bucketUrl(bucket),
      accessKey: accessKey
    },
    signature: {
      endpoint: 'sign'
    },
    chunking: {
      enabled: true,
      concurrent: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    retry: {
      enableAuto: true
    },
    callbacks: {
      onComplete: function(id, name, resp, xhr) {
        $('#drop-zone').trigger("complete", id);
      }
    }
  };

  uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader(uploaderParams);

  $("form.ajax_upload.ajax_validate").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    valuesToSave = saveFormValuesForPostToMyBackend();
    uploader.uploadStoredFiles();
    $('#drop-zone').on("complete", function(e, id) {
      performPostToMyBackend(valuesToSave);
    });
    emptyVideoFormForNextUpload();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep, this is supported.

Comment: Great to read that, please if you don't mind, take a look at my edit on question.

Comment: please show your markup as well